# Slow CSV processing in Java

Tags: java, performance, csv, nio, executorservice

I have csv sorter program which polls a folder continuously for new files, reads, sorts them and finally writes an output file and delete the original file. However it takes a huge amount of time to process the files. For e.g to process 15 files of 10,000 lines it took 18 mins. i am using threadpool with max 5 concurrency. any suggestions to improve speed would be welcome, i tried looking for alternatives to nio package for polling ..
is it normal ? what can be done better.

Main Class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("directory not specified");

    }

    Path folder = Paths.get(args[0]);
    FolderMonitor util1 = new FolderMonitor();
    util1.watchDirectoryPath(folder);

}
}
```

FolderMonitor Class :it polls the directory for new files

```
public class FolderMonitor {
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FolderMonitor.class.getName());
static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
static FileHandler fh;

public void watchDirectoryPath(Path path) {
    // Checking if path is a directory or not
    try {
        Boolean isFolder = (Boolean) Files.getAttribute(path,
                "basic:isDirectory", NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        if (!isFolder) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path: " + path
                    + " is not a folder");
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // Folder does not exists
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    try {
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        fh = new FileHandler("c:/logs/log.txt");
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);

    } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("monitoring the path: \t" + path
            + " \t for arrival of files");// good to go!!!
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "monitoring the path: \t" + path
            + " \t for arrival of files");

    // We obtain the file system of the Path
    FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem();

    // create the WatchService
    try (WatchService service = fs.newWatchService()) {

        // watching for file creation events
        path.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE);

        // Start the infinite polling loop
        WatchKey key = null;
        while (true) {
            key = service.take();

            // Dequeuing events
            Kind<?> kind = null;
            for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {
                // Get the type of the event
                kind = watchEvent.kind();
                if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind) {
                    // A new Path was created
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent)
                            .context();
                    // Output
                    System.out.println("New path created: " + newPath);
                    logger.info("New path created: " + newPath);
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    String newFilePath = path + "/" + newPath.toString();
                    Runnable worker2 = new CsvToJavaObject(newFilePath);
                    executor.execute(worker2);
                }
            }

            if (!key.reset()) {
                break; // loop
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

csvsorter class:reads ,sorts,calls print

```
public class CsvToJavaObject implements Runnable {
private final String path;

public CsvToJavaObject(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    String csvFileToRead = path;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String splitBy = ",";
    List<Stock> stockList = new ArrayList<Stock>();

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));
        br.readLine();


        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // split on comma(',')
            String[] stocks = line.split(splitBy);

            // create stock object to store values
            System.out.println(stocks[0]);
            Stock stockObject = new Stock();
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            Date d1 = null;
            try {
                d1 = sd.parse(stocks[0]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // add values from csv to stock object
            stockObject.setDate(d1);
            stockObject.setStockCode(stocks[1]);
            stockObject.setStockPrice(Integer.parseInt(stocks[2]));

            // adding stock objects to a list
            stockList.add(stockObject);

        }
        // print values stored in stockList
        CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter();
        writer.printstockList(stockList, path);

        Collections.sort(stockList,StockComparator.getInstance());
        writer.printstockList(stockList, path);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
                File todelete = new File(path);
                todelete.delete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

csvwriter :writes the sorted file to disk

```
public class CsvWriter {

public void printstockList(List<Stock> stockListToPrint, String path) {
    SimpleDateFormat sd2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    File f = new File(path);
    System.out.println(f.getName());

    // writing to file
    for (int i = 0; i < stockListToPrint.size(); i++) {

        try {
            BufferedWriter csvwrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                    "D:/stocksortedTest/" + "sorted" + f.getName()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < stockListToPrint.size(); j++) {
                sb.append(sd2.format(stockListToPrint.get(j).getDate()));
                sb.append(",");
                sb.append(stockListToPrint.get(j).getStockCode());
                sb.append(",");
                sb.append(stockListToPrint.get(j).getStockPrice());
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            csvwrite.write(sb.toString());
            csvwrite.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comparator class :

```
public class StockComparator implements Comparator<Stock> {

private static final StockComparator instance = new StockComparator();

public static StockComparator getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private StockComparator() {

}

@Override
public int compare(Stock o1, Stock o2) {
    int flag = o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
    if (flag == 0) {
        flag = o1.getStockCode().compareTo(o2.getStockCode());
    }
    return flag;
}

}
```

Comment: This question is for CodeReview.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Comment: Have you timed the code to see where it is slowest?  Have you run the JVM with the following flag -verbose:gc  ?

Comment: There are at least two things you are doing that you don't need to do: 1) Writing the file twice, once before it's sorted, and once again after, and 2) Formatting the data into a `StringBuilder` before writing it - just `append` the data straight into the `BufferedWriter`. 18 minute still seems really, really slow for 150k likes of data.

Comment: Just some notes: **1.** Drop the useless non-handling of exceptions. In your use case, letting them bubble up is the perfect solution. You save quite some lines and make it more correct and much more readable. **2.** Do any exceptions actually happen? If so, this might give us a hint. **3.** Is your CPU busy? This looks like a task a single core could do in seconds.

Comment: @msandiford yes removed the code for writing before sorting ..i didnt do anything else but execution time is in few seconds now ..i had aother instance of this program running which was also polling the same directory .although i cant say it was THE reason

Comment: @maaartinus ..i am obviously testing it with proper correct files but still have to handle file , i/o errors.cpu was busy when this happened ..but now its resolved ..its finishing execution in seconds

Answer (score 0):

It seems you write the same fiel twice

```
    // print values stored in stockList
    CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter();
    writer.printstockList(stockList, path);

    Collections.sort(stockList,StockComparator.getInstance());
    writer.printstockList(stockList, path);
```

before and after the sort

You create

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

in the `while`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `CSVJdbc` API to sort CSVs. This api treats CSV as Database and you can use any SQL command over it. This is much faster than any other APIs.

Comment: This might be an answer, but to a different question. There's no reason to believe that `CSVJdbc` should be faster than a handcrafted code.